# DynamoDB, AWS, Node.js, newb

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am exploring DynamoDB to use in a node.js project. This is my package.json

```
{
"name": "Generic-server",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"engines": {
  "node": "0.11.x"
},
"dependencies": {
  "express": "3.3.4",
  "jade": "1.1.5",
  "aws-sdk": ">= 2.0.9"
}
```

}

Now I logged into my AWS account and created a DynamoDB Table. and this is what I have in my index.js

```
 var AWS= require('aws-sdk');
 AWS.config.update({//1
 accessKeyId: 'blabla', 
 secretAccessKey: 'blabla',
 region: 'us-east-1'
 });
 var db = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2014-12-04'});
 db.listTables(function(err, data) { // 2
    console.log(data);
 });
```

So the console.log of data is always null. I can think of two areas that might be an issue ( I numbered them inline as 1 or 2 ). Any help is appreciated.

I am a .net, java, and obj c developer who is playing with node.js and AWS, just an FYI.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `apiVersion` in your `DynamoDB` constructor?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to `listTables` is the "params" field and the second one is the callback. You're passing the callback as the "params". Try like this:

```
db.listTables({}, function (err, data) {//2
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#listTables-property

Answer (score 0):

`null` is returned when a region has not been set. Define any region to receive an array response. Define the region containing your DynamoDB to have it included in the array.

[AWS DynamoDB Region list](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ddb_region)

```js
AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-west-2'
});
```